# Conversion to Swift 3 issue

Tags: ios, migration, swift3

I was following this good tutorial and I downloaded the related project: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/

Then, I opened it in XCode and converted it to Swift 3.

In the code, there was this:

```
func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
  NSLog("%@", "foundPeer: \(peerID)")
  NSLog("%@", "invitePeer: \(peerID)")
  browser.invitePeer(peerID, toSession: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
}
```

and XCode converted it to this:

```
func browser(_: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo: [String : String]?){
  //...
  browser.invitePeer(MCPeerID, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
}
```

As you can see, the first argument is no more `browser`: this causes the fact that the method can't call `invitePeer` (at that point nobody knows what `browser` is).

How can I convert my code to call invitePeer and respect the new signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change like below , Xcode migration will add _ before method first argument

```
  func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo: [String : String]?){
      //...
      browser.invitePeer(MCPeerID, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
    }
```

Comment: I tried this instantly but XCode doesn't remove the error

Comment: It worked after completely restarting XCode, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!,
             foundPeer peerId: MCPeerID!,
             withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]!) {
  browser.invitePeer(peerId, toSession: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
  // not sure if invitePeer was converted too but in any case
  // browser.invitePeer(peerId, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
}
```

From Swift3 now you must provide a label for your first argument name in your function declaration or at least an underscore (_) if you don't want to call your func with an explicit label for your first argument.

Comment: It's XCode itself who "fixed" things that way (without label)